# Passing Array from Jsp to action class

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, struts

I need to pass my array of dynamically created objects from jsp to java action class , Meanwhile i am tring following code to set array objects as a request parameter for action form . But while fetching in action class it produce null result ,as array object are not passed on to action form. Kindly provide me a right way to pass array list to action class. Thanks in advance ////

```
<script>
var i;
var arraya = new Array();
var arrayb = new Array();
var arrayc = new Array();
var idCount = 1;
function arr()
{
for (var j=0;j<idCount;j++)
{
arraya[j]=  document.getElementsByName("a"+j)[0].value;
arrayb[j]=  document.getElementsByName("b"+j)[0].value;
arrayc[j]=  document.getElementsByName("c"+j)[0].value;
}
var one=arraya.valueOf();
var two=arrayb.valueOf();
var three=arrayc.valueOf();
} 
</script>
    <input type="text" name="a0">
<input type="text" name="b0">
<input type="text" name="c0">
    <input type="button" onclick="addDiv();" value="Add"/>
<input type="hidden" name="one" value="<%= request.getParameter("one") %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="two" value="<%= request.getParameter("two") %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="three" value="<%= request.getParameter("three") %>" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing this -

Simply have input type like this. Notice no index used.

```
<input type="text" name="a"/>
<input type="text" name="b"/>
<input type="text" name="c"/>
```

In your action class you can then do this. The values will be in the order.

```
String[] a = request.getParameterValues("a");
String[] b = request.getParameterValues("b");
String[] c = request.getParameterValues("c");
```

Although since you are using Struts you should actually create an object having properties a, b and c. Use the object in array fashion.